# Searching for lib: stream audio player with play list

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, ios7

Is there working lib for play audio from web?

Answer (score 0):

The AVAudioPlayer should do it well:

[AVAudioPlayer Calss Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html)

Check:

```
    (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url fileTypeHint:(NSString *)utiString error:(NSError **)outError
```

or

```
    (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url error:(NSError **)outError
```